# trying to push two specific values into another array as a key value pair using typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

Newbie here and this is a project I'm building to learn. I'm going around in circles so forgive my ignorance please. I'm now not even sure that what I want to do is possible. I also understand that there are probably better ways to achieve my ultimate goal but this is what I have.

I have an array that includes some user input.
"participants": [ {
"name": "Cristina",
"email": "cristina@gmail",
"yourPerson": "Richard",
"spouseEmail": "Richard@gmail" } ] }

I want to pull the "name" and "youPerson" values and use them as a key:value pair. So name would be the key and yourPerson would be the value.

I thought I could use a forEach but no matter what I do I either get an undefined array or I copy the entire array, not just those two fields.

here is my code at the moment:

```
  participantArray = [];
  namePlusSpouseArray = [];
  
  submitParticipant() {
    this.participantArray.push(this.participantForm.value);
    console.log(this.participantArray)
    this.createNamePlusSpouseArray();                                             
  }


   createNamePlusSpouseArray() {
    
    this.participantArray.forEach(name  => {
     this.namePlusSpouseArray.push(this.participantArray[name]);
     console.log(this.namePlusSpouseArray)
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want a result array of key value pairs, or you want 1 object/map/dictionary/lookup of name -> youPerson

Assuming you want an array containing key value pairs, you can use `map`

```
this.namePlusSpouseArray = this.participantArray.map(participant => ({
   [participant.name]: participant.youPerson
});
```

If you want a lookup of name -> youPerson, the "namePlusSpouseArray" shouldn´t be an array but instead just an object

```
namePlusSpouseLookup = {};

this.participantArray.forEach(participant => {
    this.namePlusSpouseLookup[participant.name] = participant.youPerson;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

```js
const participantArray = {
  "participants": [ { "name": "Cristina", "email": "cristina@gmail", "yourPerson": "Richard", "spouseEmail": "Richard@gmail" } ] };

const createPair = participants => {
  return participants.map(participant => 
  ({ [participant.name]: participant.yourPerson}))
}

console.log(createPair(participantArray.participants));
```

Comment: forgive my ignorance... with this option, the values are hard coded in right? My biggest issue at the moment is getting the values in from a different array which was populated from a form. I'd really like to be able to get just the name and spouses name from the previous array into a new key value pair (I guess a map is the better option now)